# Scala List sort vs Python list sort. Execution time comparison

Tags: python, scala, performance, sorting

Scala List sort vs Python list sort. Execution time comparison.

I'm learning Scala right now.
I was interested to compare Scala's List sort with Python's list sort.
To my surprise, sorting a list of `1_000_000` integers works 5 times faster in Python than in Scala.
As far as I know, Scala is faster than python.
Who can explain the reason for such a large advantage of Python over Scala?

Scala code:

```scala
import scala.util.Random

@main
def Main(args: String*): Unit =
  def cmillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val n = 1_000_000

  val xs = List.fill(n)(Random.nextInt(n))

  var currentMillis = cmillis
  xs.sorted
  println("Sorted in " + (cmillis - currentMillis) + "ms")
```

Python code:

```py
from time import time
from random import randint

n = 1_000_000

xs = [randint(0, n) for _ in range(n)]

start = time()
sorted(xs)
print(f"Sorted in {(time() - start)* 1000} ms")
```

Comment: The tests aren’t equivalent — in the Scala version you start the timer before the list has been created (I think — unless there’s some delayed evaluation thing happening there, I don’t know Scala).  Allocating the memory in itself probably takes a non-negligible amount of time.

Comment: That is not a proper way to benchmark code, so anything you can conclude from that is meaningless.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what can you advise to benchmark code properly?

Comment: @Samwise in Scala `def` evaluates only when it calls, so `def cmillis = System.currentTimeMillis()` is like an alias.

Comment: For **Scala**: https://github.com/openjdk/jmh - For **Python**: https://pyperf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Also, `List` in Scala is a kind of linked list, while a python list is probably more or less equivalent to an `Array`.

Comment: @Jasper-M,  this is correct (for `python`).  in fact an array of integers, so might be quick in `verson 3.11` (which was improved for speed in certain cases like this).

Comment: What were the times?

Comment: One random iteration is not a performance test. Use proper performance test tools like jmh in Java.

Comment: @OleksiiHytsiv: "what can you advise to benchmark code properly?" – A degree in statistics plus a degree in computer science with a focus on interpreters, compilers, and VMs as well as operating systems (particularly schedulers and memory managers), computer organization, CPU and memory design. (Not joking.) Or, alternatively, use existing tools written by people who have that kind of background. I recommend reading (and understanding) the entire thread at https://groups.google.com/g/mechanical-sympathy/c/m4opvy4xq3U/m/7lY8x8SvHgwJ for a small(!!!) overview of some of the potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is the fastest language on Earth, if you call C code. ;-)

Jokes aside, the difference here can be explained by the fact that you are using `List` in Scala, which is a singly-linked list. While it's a very simple data structure, it has poor locality (the nodes of the list can be anywhere on the heap, leading to frequent cache misses) and more importantly its structure makes operations requiring indexing (including sorting) quite inefficient.

You can see a comparison of data structure in the Scala standard library [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html).

To make a fair comparison, you should select data structures that have a similar backing structure and use a sorting approach that is also comparable. If Python lists are backed by mutable arrays, comparing with immutable linked lists will always have mutable arrays win. If that's the case, you can use [`ArraySeq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.2.2/scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq.html#) in Scala, and instead of `sorted` (which creates a new structure) you can use [`sortInPlace`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.2.2/scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq.html#sortInPlace-fffffe55).

A couple more notes on your benchmark:

- `System.currentTimeMillis()` shouldn't be used because it's not guaranteed to be monotonic, for benchmarks `System.nanoTime()` makes sure you are measuring elapsed time
- You should run a benchmark many times to make sure you have some statistically relevant result. On the JVM you can use JMH to perform microbenchmarks that take this in consideration and also allows you to make a few runs to "warm up" the JVM (which can dynamically compile hot spots in your bytecode to native code for faster execution). I'm not sure about similar tools in the Python ecosystem, but I'm sure there's one.

Note that depending on the specific implementation of `sorted` in Python, you might still see it outperforming Scala (going back to my initial joke, if it calls C code, it's hard to beat it). I would generally expect Scala to have an advantage over Python code in terms of execution time, but this of course depends on what you are testing.

---

#### EDIT 1

A commenter correctly pointed out that a 5x factor seems *too fast* if indeed sorting on `Seq`s is done with a naive approach using indexing. I looked into the code and `Seq`s (including `List`s) seem to perform the sorting by copying themselves into an `Array` and sorting that ([code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4905801fc161300ba20bae4f7adf045b1698e831/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala#L706-L735)), which would explain why this is slow but not as slow as naively sorting an immutable linked list by indexing and swapping.

#### EDIT 2

Just out of pure curiosity, I tried to run the naive benchmark locally. Your Scala code ran in ~650ms on my laptop and the Python code took ~250ms. Just changing the `List` into an `ArraySeq` and `sorted` into `sortInPlace` makes the Scala version run in ~200ms. While this is not statistically relevant, it's an indication that those changes seem to have the expected impact. You might want to perform further benchmarks using a more scientific approach to get better results.

Comment: *"its structure makes operations requiring indexing (including sorting) quite inefficient"* - So the sorting operates on the linked list, by indexing? Doesn't it seem way too fast for that? What sorting algorithm does it use?

Comment: Very good question. I had a look at the code and noticed what happens for `Seq`s is that the list gets copied to an array and that gets sorted. I'm amending my answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: Their Python test is alright for the purpose, btw. I usually do repeat tests multiple times for accuracy, but when it's about comparison with something 5 times slower, it doesn't need to be super accurate. The times don't vary anywhere near that much. Maybe that'll change in Python 3.12, I think they're working on stuff that benefits more from warming up.

Comment: I don't know Scala, but in Python, the int objects get created in heap memory mostly sequentially. I'd expect this to be the case for Scala's linked list node objects as well. Then cache misses aren't that bad. And I'd expect this initial copying to an array to be only a small part of the time anyway. Would be good to see a speed comparison with everything in Scala "done right", btw. For info: Python does use arrays here and does use C, but the numbers are still objects, although the sorting is optimized to detect ints and compare them somewhat faster than other objects but slower than C ints.

Comment: (Cache misses during the copying, I mean. Not during the sorting. Sorting is still cache-unfriendly for Python, as the list/array only contains *references* to the number objects on the heap. And due to the sorting, the objects get accessed in increasingly random memory order.)

Comment: Thanks for all the notes with regards to Python, I'm not particularly familiar with it.

Comment: Just to be sure: Your reruns are on fresh random arrays, right? I.e., you're not repeatedly doing in-place sorting of the same array?

Comment: In Scala, at least the copying to and from an array will initially run in interpreted mode and only be compiled and optimized to native code after some warmup. And that's assuming that at least the array sorting is already done in native code like python.

Comment: But `sortInPlace` on an `ArraySeq` might not be an honest comparison. `sorted` in python also creates a new sorted list.

Comment: I did just re-run on the already sorted array. I'm not that used to mutable data structures anymore. I removed that comment and I'm on my way to the coffee machine. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm re-running with `sorted` and doing the full script every time. It does indeed seem to be around ~80 ms.

Comment: Would be good to share your testing code. [Python one](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVBLCsIwEMVtTjF0lYiVdCEUoScRKcUmGminIYlYEU_iphs9lKcxaepCQTAQMvN4n_BuD312hw6H4X50Ms2fs1yargWnWgGq1Z1x40xG1FRY-2fCw6bQEYJQQFZyzsMlRHYGSlAYCHtBV2xNwJ_eetpmElG-AGTwRUW2JSPXusoHFGM0ZRHykaKmvY2rNsFFJihO0Cjr1nChkQ1plLM5ZP4_V2htwn7a9nYZnOmnq8JUN9VO_OUaRSwWOPX47vMF) with five attempts, both in-place and not (just since @Jasper-M brought it up... it doesn't make much difference).

Comment: @KellyBundy not exactly what I tested, but you can use this for a comparison: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/CSBNEDLFQaiil2z0MbCRlw/5 Indeed in-place doesn't seem to matter (not too much at least) in this case.

Comment: If you want to go all-out, you could try running the Python code in TrufflePython, which would let it benefit from the same kinds of JIT optimizations Scala does.